# React-native ScrollView/FlatList stick to top and bottom of list

Tags: javascript, android, ios, typescript, react-native

I would like to have an item in a ScrollView or FlatList stick to the top AND bottom of the list. This is for a leaderboard component where the current players score is visible at all times.

I've tried to accomplish this with `stickyHeaderIndices` and can't seem to figure it out. Any help is appreciated.

[image: For example]

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following code to create Sticky Header and Footer

```
<FlatList
  data={ this.state.FlatListItems }
  ItemSeparatorComponent={ this.FlatListItemSeparator}
  renderItem={ ({item}) => (
    <Text
      style={styles.FlatList_Item}
      onPress={this.GetItem.bind(this, item.key)}> {item.key}
      </Text>
  )}
  ListHeaderComponent={this.Render_FlatList_Sticky_header}
  stickyHeaderIndices={[0]}
/>
```